# Undefined variable: id error while trying to update record in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This seems simple but I can't fix it
I am trying to update a record on my database, the record is successfully retrieved and shown on my update form but when I hit the submit button, I get an `Undefined variable: id` error message.

**Here is my form**

```
<form action="{{route('Person.update', $person->id)}}" method="POST">

    @csrf
    {{method_field('PUT')}}
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:20px">
        <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%;">
            <label for="occupation">{{ __('Occupation') }}</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="occupation" id="occupation" required>
                <option selected>{{$person->occupation}}</option>
                <option value="FE">{{ __('student') }}</option>
                <option value="Part">{{ __('Business') }} </option>
                <option value="Bank">{{ __('Civil servant') }} </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
            <label for="id">{{ __('ID') }}</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" value="{{$person->id}}" style="padding: 20px;" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group col-md-12" style="width: 100%;">
            <label for="name">{{ __('Name') }}</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" value="{{$person->name}}" style="padding: 20px;" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 16px; border: 0;">{{ __('Submit') }}</button>
</form>
```

**My `personController`**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $person= Person::find($id);
    return view('pages.update')->with('person', $person);
}

/**
* Update the specified resource in storage.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @param  int  $id
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function update(Request $request)
{

    //validate
    $this->validate($request,[
        'id' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required',
        'occupation' => 'required',
    ]);

    //store in the database
    $person = Person::find($id);
    $person->id = $request->input('id');
    $person->name = $request->input('name');
    $person->occupation = $request->input('occupation');

    $person->save();

    return redirect('pages.customers');
}
```

Here is the link that took me to the edit form

```
<a href="/pages/customers/{{$person->id}}" class="btn btn-warning">Update</a>
```

Comment: You should post the exact error and indicate where it occurs. But in your `update()` method, `$id` is indeed undefined. You probably want `$request->input('id')` instead.

Comment: There is no $id variable defined or retrieved in update() method. Post us the rest of the controllers code, please.

Comment: We do not know what do you exactly need. What exact id do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just pass the $id to your Update method:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

but you have to make sure your route has {id} segment in your routes file

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$request->input('id');`.

Because when you submit the form link is created with `/pages/customers/(id which you passed`) but your update operation in `update` function.

Please correct the line

```
 $person = Person::find($request->input('id'));
```

Comment: This is right + you need to remove person->id, because it is redundant.